# Can't read from app.conf file in Perl

Tags: perl, mojolicious, strawberry-perl

I have subroutine in perl that accepts parameters. Now I am trying to read from the config file using the below code.

```
sub user{
    my $self = shift;
    my $apiBaseUrl = $self->app->config->{"apiBaseUrl"};
    my $apiToken = $self->app->config->{"apiToken"};
}
```

But I am getting the error

> Can't locate object method "app" via package "test@example.com" (perhaps you forgot to load "test@example.com"?)

The parameters I am passing to the subroutine are `$username` and `$password`

This is how I am calling that subroutine, with an email and password  which I get from login form.

```
my $username = $self->param('username'); 
my $password = $self->param('password');
user($username, $password);
```

Below is the full code in the file.

```
    use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
    use Mojo::UserAgent;

sub is_logged_in {
    my $self = shift;

    return 1 if $self->session('logged_in');

    $self->render(
        inline => "<h2>Forbidden</h2><p>You're not logged in. <%= link_to 'Go to login page.' => 'login_form' %>",
        status => 403
    );
}


sub user {
    my ($username, $password) = @_;
    my $self = shift;
    my %returnResult;
    my $apiBaseUrl = $self->app->config->{'apiBaseUrl'};
    my $apiToken = $self->app->config->{'apiToken'};
    my $url = $apiBaseUrl.'/auth/login/check?email='.$username.'&password='.$password.'';
    my $header = {'api-token' => $apiToken};

    my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    my $res = $ua->post( $url => $header )->result;
    if($res->is_success)
    {
        my $content= $res -> json;
        my $decoded_email = $content->{'email'};

        $returnResult{'fn'} = $content->{'fn'};
        $returnResult{'ln'} = $content->{'ln'};
        $returnResult{'roles'} = $content->{'roles'};
        if($username eq $decoded_email)
        {$returnResult{'logged_in'} = 1;}
        else
        {$returnResult{'logged_in'} = 0;}
        return %returnResult;

    }
    else
    {
        return $res->status_line;
    }
}


sub on_user_login {

    my $self = shift;
    my $username = $self->param('username');
    my $password = $self->param('password');
    my %userDetails = user($username, $password);

        if ($userDetails{'logged_in'} == 1) {

        $self->session(logged_in => 1);
        $self->session(username => $username);
        $self->session(userDetails => \%userDetails);
        $self->redirect_to('restricted');
    } else {
        $self->flash(message => 'Incorrect username/password!');
        $self->redirect_to('/');
    }
}

1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `user` is supposed to be a method of a class.    It should be called  like  `$class_instance->user(...)`

Comment: Your error message tells you, that the parameter of the sub, `$self`, is not the object you expect it to be, but a string containing a mail address.

Comment: @nlu           How can I instantiate the object. All the examples shows `my $self = shift;`

Comment: @user1690835: This depends on how you use Mojolicious. I believe with `Mojolicious::Lite` the object containing `app` is being created for you. You should show us more context.

Comment: @nlu           I am new to Perl. So didn't understand what you meant by context.

Comment: @user1690835: This has nothing to do with Perl. I just meant, where `user` is called, when and how the main mojolicious object is instantiated etc. If you do not understand, what I mean by this, you should revoke this question and first try to understand how Perl works, how OO in Perl works and then how your framework (mojolicious) works.

Comment: @nlu           I am calling `user` from another subroutine. In `user` I am checking the username and password are correct and return true or false.

Comment: @user1690835: What about the object you pass to user?

Comment: @nlu           It is `email` and `password` which I get from login form. `my $username = $self->param('username');    my $password = $self->param('password');user($username, $password);`

Comment: So `user` should be a method of `$self` - then you should call it `$self->user(...). See first comment of user wolfrevokcats.

Comment: @nlu           I am returning a hash from the method `user`, and I am assigning it as `my %userDetails = user($username, $password)` so when I call the method using `$self->user(...)` the program is not working as expected.

Comment: Those two things are unrelated. You can assign the return value of a method call just like you can the one from a function call. Please show more of your code and be very specific. Not working is a completely useless description of an error. A device that is not turned on is not working, just like a device that is broken. I can't tell anything from that statement.

Comment: @simbabque     I have updated the question. Not working means login always fails.

Comment: In what file did you put the `user` method? You are not telling me enough. It's like asking me to diagnose why your car doesn't start without showing me the car.

Comment: @simbabque     Everything is in the same file.

Comment: Please edit again and remove code that you don't actually have in your program. Then include the full code of the `user` method and the full code of the method where you call it. Also include the top ten lines of your file. Do not alter anything in the code. Show me exactly what you have in your editor. Copy and paste it in here please.

Comment: @simbabque     I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> my $username = $self->param('username'); 
> my $password = $self->param('password');
> user($username, $password);
> ```

You are using your `user` sub as a *function*, and not as a *method*. Perl is a very flexible programming language that allows you to mix functional, procedural and object oriented programming styles in the same program. Sometimes that can get confusing.

You can recognize OOP (*object oriented programming*) in Perl when a sub has `$self` as the first argument because there is a convention to always name the object itself like that. Other languages use `this` instead. Another giveaway is when there is a variable followed by an arrow `->` followed by an identifier.

```
$obj->method(@args);
```

You've already done that in your code when you got the parameters from `$self`. I suspect you are using this in a Mojolicious::Controller, and you've put your `sub user` in the same file.

The error message you are seeing is because your first argument to the function is the email address in `$username`. You left out the `$self->` part, which tells Perl to call this as a method on `$self`. Under the hood, it will look into the identifier on the left (which is `$self`) to see what class that thing has. It will then look into the *namespaces* (called *packages* in Perl) of all the things in the inheritance tree of that class to find the identifier on the right (which is `user`). In our case, it will find a sub `user` right in this same package. It then calls that function `user` and passes the thing on the left (`$self`) as the first argument, and `$username` and `$password` as the second and third arguments.

So what you need to do is:

```
$self->user($username, $password);
```

The code in your sub is correct (but does not actually use the two arguments).

Comment: When I use `$self->user($username, $password);` program is not working correctly. See the comment I added to question. So instead I passed the `$self` variable as a parameter `user_exists($self,$username, $password);` and is working correctly.